# How to use both in and like in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to use `restrictions.in` & `restrictions.like` in a same criteria. Is that possible?
My case is:

```
public List<User> getUserByMsisdns(final Set<String> msisdns)   
{
   try {
         final Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
         criteria.add(Restrictions.in("msisdn", msisdns));  
         ...
```

Here it compares with the list of exact msisdns. But it should compare with like.
For E.g : if My Db contains numbers 919787458451, 919784548745 & am passing a value such as %9787458451 then it should return the result.

Comment: When your like query is `%9787458451` it will only match 919787458451, not 919784548745.

Comment: Yes that is what I want since I am passing only 9787458451. That is for example. If I pass both 9787458451 & 9784548745 with % (like) in the input comparable value then it will return both. My question is how to do that like & in both in hibernate?

Comment: @karthi Can you show mapping or annotation for `msisdn`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `restrictions.in & restrictions.like` in same criteria. You will find some good examples [here](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/). Just take care how you order them. Which has to be performed first, conditions to be checked and so on..